# Socket does not accept connections

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I have a server socket accepting client socket connections. Accept is in a thread

socket creation

```
int ServerSocket::CreateSocket(int port)
{
listenfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
unsigned long iMode = 1;

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port); 


ioctlsocket(listenfd, FIONBIO, &iMode);

if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    return 0;
}

if (listen(listenfd, 20) < 0)
{
    return 0;
}

return listenfd;
}
```

Socket Accept

```
void ServerSocket::AcceptClients_1(void * p)
{
struct sockaddr_in  cli_addr;

// get a pointer to the ServerSocket object
ServerSocket * pThis = (ServerSocket *)p;
int iResult, cli_len;
cli_len = sizeof(cli_addr);
struct timeval tv = { 0, 1000 };  
SOCKET s = pThis->GetSocket();
fd_set rfds;

FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(s, &rfds);

while (!pThis->ShutDownRequested)
{
   iResult = select(s+1, &rfds, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, &tv);
   if(iResult > 0)
   {
         // never comes here
         SOCKET sclient =  accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, 
                            &cli_len);
    }
   else if (iResult == 0)   /// timeout
   {
        continue;
   }
   // error comes here are going to accept 2nd time
   DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
   return;
 }  
}
```

The code comes on select(). Returns 0 the first time but second time always returns -1 with error 10022. I don't understand why. Please help.

Comment: side note, in your memset, `'0'` and `0` are not the same thing. Also, you should be using `WSAGetLastError`, not `GetLastError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `pThis->GetSocket()` is correctly returning the `listenfd`.  Also, you should reinitialize `cli_len = sizeof(cli_addr);` before each call to `accept` (it's a  value-result argument).

Comment: Please note that it does not get to the accept() even once. First time select() returns 0 and second time -1 with errorcode of 10022

Comment: Also do your `FD_ZERO` and `FD_SET` in the loop before the select.

Answer (score 0):

iResult=0 does not always mean timeout, for non-blocking sockets, you need to check WSAGetLastError and deal with some error codes, for example WSAEWOULDBLOCK means you need to wait next event on this socket.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes you are right but the problem is that I get 10022 error not WSAEWOULDBLOCK. I have changed my code to take care of WSAEWOULDBLOCK but this does not solve the problem